# How can Excel automatically move to highlighted cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I have been playing around with Gantt chart template and edited some contents. One of the downsides I've noticed is that when I change the date in cell "E4". The cell on the left-hand section will be highlighted but not moved automatically.

When I change the date to 2/2/2017. The date column will be highlighted but I have to manually scroll to that date.

Question: Is there any way that Excel can automatically move the sheet to selected date?

[image: Gantt Chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Worksheet_Change()` event to do this.  In the *worksheet* you want this to run on, add this code. (Right click the worksheet tab, and go to "View Code"):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dateCell As Range

If Target.Address = "$E$4" Then
    Set dateCell = Range("A49:A50").Find(what:=Target.Value)
    If dateCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Date not found")
    Else
        dateCell.Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Note: Adjust the `Set dateCell = Range([this range])` to be the range of your dates you want to "jump" to after you enter the date.

Comment: @AlexisKeatnuxsuo if this works for you, do you mind marking as the answer? (Click the check mark left of the post)